# Name of the high pitch sound produced when objects are hit against each other underwater

Tags: names, sounds

For instance, when a spoon or ice cube hits a glass of water

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word for that sound would likely be onomatopoeic like...

***Ping
Tinkle
Clink
Ding***

> Definition of Onomatopoeia
>
> Onomatopoeia is the formation of a word
>   from a sound associated with what is named (e.g., cuckoo, sizzle).
>   However the word Onomatopoeia can also be used to describe the use of
>   such words for rhetorical effect. For example, in the sentence 'The
>   poet Tennyson used onomatopoeia as a linguistic device'.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the circumstances, I believe it is best to create your own onomatopoeia.  I 'd go with something like:  "shplink" .

Answer (score 0):

> [**ting**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ting)
>   *n*.
>   A single light metallic sound, as of a small bell.

You might also be interested in the similar [ping](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ping), which covers the underwater part (it comes from the noise made by sonar equipment).